# Count Video play minute in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My `.Net` project contains the play video button, **in for each loop**. When users visit the website and click on the particular button based on the selected video it plays the video and, the video gets displayed in a **model popup**, which is working **fine**.

```
@{foreach (LIST)
{
  <button id="btnPlay" type="button" onclick="PlayVideo('@item.ViedoUrl')"
             data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" class="btnPlay">
    <img src="/Images/VideoImage.jpeg" class="" height="30">                                                        
  </button>
}
```

Here is my model pop-up code.

```
<div id="videoModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog model-full">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Video</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" onclick="PlayVideoCount();" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <video id="VideoId" autoplay="" controls="" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code to display the video.

```
function PlayVideo(videoUrl) {
   var video = document.getElementById('VideoId');
   var videoUrlCount = videoUrl;
   video.src = videoUrl;
   video.play();
 }
```

Now I want to count how many minutes users watched the video when the user clicks on the close button. For that **onclick="PlayVideoCount()"**, call the JavaScript function.

```
function PlayVideoCount() {
       
}
```

How to calculate the watch minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user click to watch video keep current date and when close the modal calculate differences between current time and the time you kept when play button pressed

```js
var startDate;
function PlayVideo(video) {
    console.log(video + " is playing");
    startDate = new Date();
}

function PlayVideoCount() {
    console.log("stooped video");
    var diff = (new Date() - startDate);

    var minutes = Math.floor((diff / 1000) / 60);
    var second = Math.floor((diff / 1000));
    console.log("watched video " + minutes + " minutes");
    console.log("watched video " + second + " seconds");
}
```

```html
<button id="btnPlay" type="button" onclick="PlayVideo('Viedo1')"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" class="btnPlay">
    play video
</button>

<button onclick="PlayVideoCount()">close modal</button>
```